# Spring boot Apache CXF exception trace

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, cxf, jaxb2

I'm trying to build a springboot +  apache cxf application. A simple hello world application works fine but when i try to use my custom objects its throwing error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpoint' defined in class path resource [com/citi/gpf/ah/config/EndpointConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.citi.gpf.ah.AHServicesApp.main(AHServicesApp.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:375) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.citi.gpf.ah.config.EndpointConfig.endpoint(EndpointConfig.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.citi.gpf.ah.config.EndpointConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd140a18.CGLIB$endpoint$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.citi.gpf.ah.config.EndpointConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd140a18$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dbcd1e21.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.citi.gpf.ah.config.EndpointConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd140a18.endpoint(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:329) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86) ~[cxf-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:470) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:695) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:530) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:263) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:103) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:168) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:460) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:358) ~[cxf-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:246) ~[cxf-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:472) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:327) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Form the exception trace

> Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

it is obvious that it occurs due to a name conflict but no details about which field is causing the issue. Is there any way to get more detailed log? Specifying the field with error?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions happens due to missing "default zero-arg constructors" - can you verify once?

Comment: No. All of them have no-arg constructor